# Two way binding to an object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a textbox in WPF which looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="EmployeeIdTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsEnabled="False" Margin="5,5,10,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
    Text="{Binding 
        ElementName=_selectedEmployee, 
        Path=Id, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And the binding source looks like this:

`private Employee _selectedEmployee = Employee.GetEmployees();`

I researched on the internet to find a solution to make the textbox update if object changes and vice versa, but my problem is that no change happens. What am i missing here?

Comment: how do you set `DataContext` for the Window?

Comment: I think you are missing a lot. _selectedEmployee must be a property, not a variable, you have to raise a property changed event after setting the property...

Comment: @Pikoh, not necessary. it might happen there is something like `EmployeeIdTextBox.DataContext = _selectedEmployee;` in code behind

Comment: @ASh,hmm..it could be, but that's something i think i would never do. Anyway, it's obvious there's not enough info to answer :)

Comment: @Pikoh yes i came across something like that. How exactly should the PropertyChanged event be raised? Can you please suggest me a good article if possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-way binding in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320028/two-way-binding-in-wpf)

Comment: @bit link would help you Yasith

Answer (score 1):

You should bind to public properties.

```
public Employee SelectedEmployee {get;set;}

...

SelectedEmployee = Employee.GetEmployees();
```